# Failing to pass session data to separate backend next.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session, next.js

I need help figuring out why I am unable to access session data in express.js.

Here is my use session:

```js
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret_key',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
}));
```

I have a /login endpoint as follows:

```js
app.post("/staff/login", async (req, res, next) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    console.log(req.body);
    if (!username || !password) {
        return next(new BadRequestError());
    }

    staffLogin(req.body).then(response => {
        req.session.profile = {hi: "plzwork"};
        res.send("{}");
    }).catch(next);
});
```

Then - in my NEXT.JS app with app directory, I login as follows:

```js
const handleLogin = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const username = e.target[0].value;
  const password = e.target[1].value;
  const data = {
    username: username,
    password: password
  }

  const response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:3000/staff/login", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
  });

  const res = await response.json();
  if(res.error) {
    setError(res.error.message);
  } else {
    // Successful login, redirect
    setError('');
  }
};
```

Then, when redirecting to /dashboard, in order to check the user is truly authenticated, I have a /session endpoint as follows, which is called from SSR in Next:

```js
app.get("/staff/session", sessionChecker, async (req, res, next) => {
    res.json({ success: 1 });
})
```

```js
const sessionChecker = (req, res, next) => {    
  if (req.session.profile) {
      console.log(`Found User Session`.green);
      next();
  } else {
      console.log(`No User Session Found`.red);
      next(new UnauthorizedError());
    }
};
```

In NEXT.JS, on loading /dashboard, server-side rendering is used to call this /session endpoint, and the session cookie is taken from the client and passed to the server using the Cookie header, like so:

```js
const checkLoggedIn = async () => {
    const cookiesString = cookies().getAll()
        .map((cookie) => `${cookie.name}=${encodeURIComponent(cookie.value)}`)
        .join('; ');
    console.log(cookiesString);
    const isLoggedIn = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:3000/staff/session", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            'Cookie': cookiesString,
            'Accept': 'application/json',
        },
    });

    console.log(isLoggedIn);

    if ((await isLoggedIn.json()).success) {
        console.log("logged in");
    } else {
        redirect('/');
    }
};
```

Now here's the problem: The session "profile" never gets set as it should upon successful login. The set-cookie header is sent in the response of the server, with something similar to `connect-sid==s%3A23YM3ATuQjrNP4CC_XYLWLIev3Vea4US.j%2B%2FfAypRFIWuQ6n7fwz2nbOwI9UEvXHCPYrVmsWmUjI; Path=/; HttpOnly`. However, when accessing req.session, I only get this:

```
Session {
  cookie: { path: '/', _expires: null, originalMaxAge: null, httpOnly: true }
}
```